# How to make a certain web app on Apache server to use different proxy for downloading?

Tags: linux, proxy, apache-2.4

I have couple apps on my apache server. It all works fine. My issue is that I want one of the apps to use a different http(s) proxy when downloading stuff through that app.

I am using a web article scraper (similar to instapaper) to save local copies of online articles. So I want this web app (that is under /www on my server) to use a different proxy(connection) when downloading articles. This is necessary for me because I block certain ip ranges on my server and sometimes the articles might be served by some of these ips. The proxy  will be running on a cps somewhere else.

I want to be able to change the connection proxy for this particular app that is running on the Apache server, instead of changing the whole  http proxy of my system.

I am on Debian using Apache

Thanks

Comment: What is the server's IP address, and the IP addresses of the proxies? (trust me, it *is* relevant)

Answer (score 0):

You can use directive SetEnv to set environment variables.

So if the specific app runs in it's own virtual host, you can set the following:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ...
    ...
    SetEnv http_proxy "10.20.30.40:8888"
</VirtualHost>
```

You can set it in directory context (if the app doesn't run under it's own vhost).